# How do I copy line segment on HTML5 CANVAS tag rotate it and place it next to the original segment?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Firstly I have tried to find solution to my problem but I do not think that I know how to search online for solutions.
Okay so I have this image that is drawn via line segments :  moveTo, lineTo etc.

As you can see we could divide the image into 4 parts that are essentially the same but rotated and placed next to other elements. What I mean by this if you draw 4 lines from the center with 90 angle you can notice the same pattern.

Basically what I am trying to do is to have one part of the canvas drawn manually by inserting moveTo and the rest to somehow generate to save some time ofc.

Not sure if I explained well my problem, excuse me this is my first stackoverflow question posted.

I mean I found a way to do this by having 4 different CANVAS elements and then rotate each canvas. I am looking for a way to do everything in one CANVAS element. But not sure if that is possible.

My code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Model 1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body  onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas_id" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<!-- 1---->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function draw() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_id');
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                //top left square
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
                ctx.lineTo(10, 40);
                ctx.lineTo(40, 40);
                ctx.lineTo(40, 10);
                ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fill();

                //down left square
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(10, 100);
                ctx.lineTo(10, 130);
                ctx.lineTo(40,130);
                ctx.lineTo(40, 100);
                ctx.lineTo(10, 100);
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fill();

                //top right square
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(100, 10);
                ctx.lineTo(130, 10);
                ctx.lineTo(130, 40);
                ctx.lineTo(100, 40);
                ctx.lineTo(100, 10);
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fill();

                //down right square
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
                ctx.lineTo(130, 100);
                ctx.lineTo(130, 130);
                ctx.lineTo(100, 130);
                ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fill();

                //center figure

                //1
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(70, 10);
                ctx.lineTo(10, 70);
                ctx.lineTo(70, 130);
                ctx.lineTo(130, 70);
                ctx.lineTo(70, 10);

                // inside
                ctx.moveTo(70, 30);
                ctx.lineTo(30, 70);
                ctx.lineTo(70, 110);
                ctx.lineTo(110, 70);
                ctx.lineTo(70, 30);

                //square 1
                ctx.moveTo(60, 60);
                ctx.lineTo(80, 60);
                ctx.lineTo(80, 80);
                ctx.lineTo(60, 80);
                ctx.lineTo(60, 60);

                //square 2
                ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
                ctx.lineTo(90, 50);
                ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
                ctx.lineTo(50, 90);
                ctx.lineTo(50, 50);

                ctx.stroke();
                }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood well what you need.
You can either parametrize your `draw` function with an `angle`, and a `x, y` position parameters, or copy, rotate and paste a part of the canvas. I assumed you would prefer the second solution.
Basically, copy your canvas, rotate it, draw something, then restore your changes. 
You can use this function:

```
function draw(canvas, ctx, x, y, angle) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.translate(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2));
  // drawing begin
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(10, 40);
  ctx.lineTo(40, 40);
  ctx.lineTo(40, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(30, 30);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
  // drawing end
  ctx.restore();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
// draw something with a 90° angle
draw(canvas, ctx, 0, 0, 90);

// draw something with a 180° angle
draw(canvas, ctx, 0, 0, 180);
```

The `x` and `y` coordinates are the ones of the rotated canvas, so `0, 0` will be in the angle each time.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/kt3f782o/19/